# How do I make Gatsby render headers server-side?

Tags: javascript, gatsby, prerender

I'm adding some SEO tags to a Gatsby website using Helmet, it looks roughly like this (and this approach seems to be [recommended by Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/add-seo-component/)):

```
<Helmet
  …
  link= {
    canonicalLink 
      ? [{ rel: 'canonical', key: 'canonical', href: canonicalLink }]
      : []
  }
  meta={[
    {
      name: `description`,
      content: metaDescription,
    },
    …
  ].concat(meta)}
/>
```

I've noticed that if I do `gatsby build`, run a web server and open the page in my browser I can see the headers correctly rendered in the inspector. However if I open `index.html` in my IDE I can't find any of the tags. Hence, the tags are being rendered in the client-side.

I'd like to have the SEO tags rendered server-side, so that I'm not relying on web crawlers to parse the Javascript on the page. How do I do that in Gatsby?

Comment: Just put them in the HTML instead of using the SEO plugin to do it in JS?

Comment: Many of them need to be calculated on-the-fly. I'd like to put them in the HTML that is generated by JS rather than the client-side JS, but I don't know how.